# How to show search and sort options all the time in dataTable irrespective of iDisplayLength ?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, datatables

I have 12 rows and because I have kept iDisplayLength as 25, dataTable header search (and the drop down) are not being shown as well as the sort option. How can I keep them enabled all the time as they are very handy ?

here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#name').dataTable({
    sPaginationType: "full_numbers",
    bJQueryUI: true
    "iDisplayLength": 25
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this your whole code?

I've just tested it and it seems to work.
See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U7A2z/)

There was only one error, a missing comma after `bJQueryUI: true`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#name').dataTable({
        sPaginationType: "full_numbers",
        bJQueryUI: true,
       //--------------/\
        "iDisplayLength": 25
    });
});
```

Did also work without the dataTables CSS file...looks a bit messy but works.